# Saving dotm to docm - embed macros in docm

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

When I save a `.dotm` file with macros to a `.docm` file, the macro's aren't embedded in the `.dotm` file.

When I send the file to a colleague, he needs the `.dotm`, along with it to be able to use the macro's.

I want the code to be embedded in the `.dotm`, so it can be used as a standalone file.

Any way to do so?

Comment: That is the default behavior. Perhaps write a code in `.dotm` which copies the relevant procedures to the `.docm` file?

Comment: Do you need to use a dotm?  Why not just use a docm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this in cases where the .dotm is opened using a double click, and a new document is created from the .dotm by default. In this case the new document links to the macros in the template but does not copy them into the document. When you save the .dotm as a .docm, you're opening the original template and not working with a new document, right?

Comment: Indeed, any suggestion to get around this?

Comment: Make sure you're working with the template (.dotm) file and not a new document created from the file. Then save the template as a .docm file. The default behavior for windows is to create a new document when the tempalte is doubleclicked, so make sure to either use the open dialog in Word, or right click the file and select the Open option (second from the top).

Comment: Thanks it indeed is default behavior, i think ill distribute a .docm instead.